# Labeling single road once per data driven page?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, labeling, data-driven-pages, annotation

I am working with data driven pages and need to label a long road that spans multiple pages.and convert those labels to annotation.

Is there a way for ArcGIS Desktop to treat each page as its own segment, forcing it to place a new label on each page?

I have messed around with the connect features/one label per feature/one label per feature segment/one label per feature part options in the label density tab of the label layer properties but have had no luck.

Comment: Why does the label need to be converted to annotation?